# Mapbox CN vs Global Compatibility

Tags: mapbox

Mapbox has announced a China Version, is the API or SDK compatible to the Global version?

How do we switch between the CN and Global Mapbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mapbox.cn](https://blog.mapbox.com/announcing-mapbox-cn-369a1a484676) is the same mapping platform as Mapbox worldwide, but modified to meet the needs of the Chinese market. You can see specific comparisons on the [Mapbox.cn](https://www.mapbox.cn/) website.

Switching between the two versions will be different on [each platform](https://blog.mapbox.com/mobile-plugins-for-mapbox-cn-d59c7ab5452b). See instructions for [iOS](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/plugins/overview/) and [Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/china/).

Disclaimer: I work at Mapbox